# Difference between hadoop fs -put and hadoop fs -copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

`-put`  and `-copyFromLocal` are documented as identical, while most examples use the verbose variant -copyFromLocal. Why?

Same thing for `-get` and `-copyToLocal`

Comment: please check this link which mentioned the details in source code level http://hakunamapdata.com/why-put-is-better-than-copyfromlocal-when-coping-files-to-hdfs/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Latest**

There is **no difference** between `-copyFromLocal` and the `-put` command.

**Reference**: [Hadoop's documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal).

---

**Earlier**

`-copyFromLocal` is similar to `-put` command, except that the source is **restricted to a local** file reference.

So basically, you can do with *put*, all that you do with `-copyFromLocal`, but not vice-versa.

Similarly,

`-copyToLocal` is similar to *get* command, except that the destination is **restricted to a local file** reference.

Hence, you can use *get* instead of `-copyToLocal`, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 41):

Let's make an example:
If your HDFS contains the path: `/tmp/dir/abc.txt`
And if your local disk also contains this path then the hdfs API won't know which one you mean, unless you specify a scheme like `file://` or `hdfs://`. Maybe it picks the path you did not want to copy.

Therefore you have `-copyFromLocal` which is preventing you from accidentally copying the wrong file, by limiting the parameter you give to the local filesystem.

`Put` is for more advanced users who know which scheme to put in front.

It is always a bit confusing to new Hadoop users which filesystem they are currently in and where their files actually are.

Comment: What do you mean by "the hdfs API won't know which one you mean"? For '-put' the source is always the first argument. Or you mean that some users may confuse '-put' with '-get' ?

Comment: No, neither way. We are speaking about two different file systems here. HDFS and local file system (say ext4). By using `bin/hadoop fs -put /tmp/somepath /user/hadoop/somepath` the command actually does not know whether `/tmp/somepath` exists in both filesystems, or just in local filesystem. Same thing with the destination path.

Comment: So the first parameter is not always an local fs path so to say. You can `put` from one HDFS to another if you'd like. `-copyFromLocal` will ensure that it just picks from the local disk and uploads to HDFS.

Comment: Why does it need to know? Your command example (and the -copyFromLocal variant) always copies /tmp/somepath/* from local to /user/hadoop/somepath/* on HDFS, and creates /user/hadoop/somepath directories if they are not yet created. Right?

Comment: No, put would prefer the HDFS scheme instead of the local file system. copyFromLocal would not do this and pick it from local file system.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for explaining why you would ever need or want to use -copyFromLocal

Answer (score 21):

Despite what is claimed by the documentation, as of now (Oct. 2015), both `-copyFromLocal` and `-put` are the same.

From the online help:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -help copyFromLocal 
-copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] [-l] <localsrc> ... <dst> :
  Identical to the -put command.
```

And this is confirmed by [looking at the sources](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/CopyCommands.java?revision=1619197&view=markup#l267), where you can see that the CopyFromLocal class extends the Put class, but without adding any new behavior:

```
  public static class CopyFromLocal extends Put {
    public static final String NAME = "copyFromLocal";
    public static final String USAGE = Put.USAGE;
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Identical to the -put command.";
  }

  public static class CopyToLocal extends Get {
    public static final String NAME = "copyToLocal";
    public static final String USAGE = Get.USAGE;
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Identical to the -get command.";
  }
```

As you might notice it, this is exactly the same for `get`/`copyToLocal`.

Answer (score 4):

- both are the same except
- `-copyFromLocal` is restricted to copy from local while `-put` can take file from any (other HDFS/local filesystem/..)

Answer (score 1):

They're the same. This can be seen by printing usage for `hdfs` (or `hadoop`) on a command-line:

```
$ hadoop fs -help
# Usage: hadoop fs [generic options]
# [ . . . ]
# -copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] [-t <thread count>] <localsrc> ... <dst> :
#   Identical to the -put command.

# -copyToLocal [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst> :
#   Identical to the -get command.
```

Same for [`hdfs`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html) (the `hadoop` command specific for HDFS filesystems):

```
$ hdfs dfs -help
# [ . . . ]
# -copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] [-t <thread count>] <localsrc> ... <dst> :
#   Identical to the -put command.

# -copyToLocal [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst> :
#   Identical to the -get command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `-put` & `-copyFromLocal` commands work exactly the same. You cannot use `-put` command to copy files from one HDFS directory to another. Let's see this with an example: say your root has two directories, named 'test1' and 'test2'. If 'test1' contains a file 'customer.txt' and you try copying it to test2 directory

```
$ hadoop fs -put /test1/customer.txt /test2
```

It will result in *`'no such file or directory'`* error since 'put' will look for the file in the local file system and not hdfs.
They are both meant to copy files (or directories) from the local file system to HDFS, only.

Comment: Maybe if you specify the filesystem in the first argument, it wouldnt read the local? `hadoop fs -put hdfs:///test1/customer.txt hdfs:///test2`?