# HDFS getting confused if same path is present on local node as well

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am using Hadoop provided by CDH 5.4.1 cluster.
The issue I'm facing is that there is a directory on HDFS with path */tmp/data*
It has some csv files say abc.csv
Now this same folder is present on one of the node's (say node 1) local linux fs as well and containing a csv file **xyz.csv**.

When I am running the following command from the node1: `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/data/*.csv` I am expecting the output to show abc.csv however I get an error saying

```
ls: `/tmp/data/xyz.csv': No such file or directory
```

The same command gives correct output when run on other nodes which dont have this same folder path on their local linux fs.

My understanding was that since I am using `hdfs dfs` command Hadoop should be looking in **dfs** space only and not get confused with local Linux filesystem but that seems to be incorrect.

Please provide pointers on what could be the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Found another useful link which explains the difference between put and copyFromLocal and also indirectly answers this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811284/difference-between-hadoop-fs-put-and-hadoop-fs-copyfromlocal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of Bash (or whatever your shell of choice) globbing and expanding the wildcard before passing the argument to the HDFS command.  There is a file on your local file system at /tmp/data/xyz.csv.  Therefore, the command that really gets invoked is `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/data/xyz.csv`.  Since xyz.csv does not exist in your HDFS cluster, it is reported as file not found.

You can work around this by wrapping your arguments in single quotes to prevent globbing expansion:

```
> # local file system
> ls /tmp/data/*.csv
/tmp/data/xyz.csv

> # attempting to check HDFS, but wildcard expansion happens before invoking command
> hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/data/*.csv
ls: `/tmp/data/xyz.csv': No such file or directory

> # wrap in single quotes to prevent globbing expansion
> hdfs dfs -ls '/tmp/data/*.csv'
-rw-r--r--   3 naurc001 supergroup          0 2017-02-02 11:52 /tmp/data/abc.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your solution works fine for me. However I am not clear on how the directory got created in first place on local linux fs. All i am doing is pushing some csv files to hdfs at /tmp/data location. This is happening on some rare scenarios only which I am not able to reproduce. Any pointers on this would be of help.

Comment: If paths are getting created on the local file system unexpectedly, then perhaps some of your `hdfs dfs` commands are accidentally creating directories and file locally instead of on HDFS.  This would happen if the path argument passed to the command is a file URI (prefixed with `file://`) or if the command accidentally runs without the full Hadoop configuration (core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml) in effect.  If configuration isn't found, then the default `fs.defaultFS` is the local file system.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding was that since I am using hdfs dfs command hadoop should be looking in dfs space only and not get confused with local linux fs

Only if you've correctly setup your Hadoop client XML configuration files to use the `hdfs://` URI and not `file://`

In core-site.xml, the default value of `fs.defaultFS` is `file://`

---

This value should be correctly set within a CDH or HDP managed environment, though

Comment: Hi cricket_007, the value is correctly set in the file and pointing to hdfs:// only